# No dashed border Outlook HTML email

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have an email with a table. I want to add a dashed border on top, but in Outlook 2013 the dashed border isn't showing.

My HTML code:

```
<table width="700" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 5px 0; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-color: #000; border-top-style: solid;" width="25%">Naam lid 1: Test 1</td>
        <td width="25%" style="border-top-width: 1px; border-top-color: #000; border-top-style: solid;"></td>
        <td width="25%" style="border-top-width: 1px; border-top-color: #000; border-top-style: solid;"></td>
        <td width="25%" style="border-top-width: 1px; border-top-color: #000; border-top-style: solid;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">Ban lid 1: joro</td>
        <td width="25%"></td>
        <td width="25%"></td>
        <td width="25%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-top-width: 1px !important; border-top-color: black !important; border-top-style: dashed !important;">
            <div style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" align="left">T-shirt</div>
        </td>
        <td style="border-top-width: 1px !important; border-top-color: black !important; border-top-style: dashed !important;">
            <div style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" align="left">Trui</div>
        </td>
        <td style="border-top-width: 1px !important; border-top-color: black !important; border-top-style: dashed !important;">
            <div style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" align="left">Sjaaltje</div>
        </td>
        <td style="border-top-width: 1px !important; border-top-color: black !important; border-top-style: dashed !important;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Anyone an idea, why it isn't showing, is it even possible to show a dashed border in Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `!important`statement was failing in outlook, removing it solved the problem.